# r - phyloseq - ordination of taxa other than species (family, order, etc.)

Tags: r, phylogeny, phyloseq

I have reviewed the phyloseq tutorials, but I can't determine how to determine the stress level and plot the ordination of a specific taxa (other than species), such as family or other classifications.

In order to illustrate my point, here is the following R code:

```
library("phyloseq")

data(GlobalPatterns)

GP <- GlobalPatterns
```

This is an attempt to isolate the family taxa only

```
GPtaxa <- tax_table(GP)[, "Family"]

GPotu <- otu_table(GP)

GPsd <- sample_data(GP)

GPpt <- phy_tree(GP)

GPnew <- phyloseq(GPotu, GPsd, GPtaxa, GPpt)
```

Using the default GlobalPatterns data set

```
GP1 <- ordinate(GP, "NMDS", engine = "monoMDS", maxit = 200, try = 100)

GP1$stress

# [1] 0.1612348
```

Using the revised GlobalPatterns data set with family as the only taxa

```
GP2 <- ordinate(GPnew, "NMDS", engine = "monoMDS", maxit = 200, try = 100)

GP2$stress

# [1] 0.1612348
```

How do you perform ordination of a taxa other than species using phyloseq?

I know how to do this in vegan, but I need a phyloseq solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `tax_table()` accessor method did not subset or agglomerate as you suggested in the post. It merely returned the taxonomy table alone, subsetted to the `"Family"` column in common matrix bracket notation.

What you are looking for is `tax_glom` first to do the agglomeration.

```
library("phyloseq")
data(GlobalPatterns)
GPnew <- tax_glom(GlobalPatterns, "Family")
```

And now the ordination

```
ord1 <- ordinate(GPnew, "NMDS", "bray")
plot_ordination(GPnew, ord1, color="SampleType")
```